# Failed to parse source map while working on local machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> WARNING in ./node_modules/timeago.js/esm/index.js Module Warning (from
> ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Failed to parse source map from
> '/Users/mayankrawat/Desktop/Development/maps/frontend/node_modules/timeago.js/src/index.ts'
> file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> '/Users/mayankrawat/Desktop/Development/maps/frontend/node_modules/timeago.js/src/index.ts'

I don't know why I got this error when starting my React app .

Comment: Add some code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems a [bug](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/discussions/11767) in **CRA 5.0** . you can ignore it with :   Creating  a `.env` file in the root directory of your project (next to your package.json file).
then add `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` to it .

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how disabling all source maps because of (possible) one package without them, is / should be the accepted answer?!

Answer (score 1):

I used a different workaround that allowed me to keep source maps, by creating a `config-overrides.js`

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/discussions/11767
    console.log("config-overrides.js: Ignoring source map warning https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/discussions/11767");
    config.ignoreWarnings = [/Failed to parse source map/];

    return config;
};
```

Note I'm using `react-app-rewired` for this to work

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@excalidraw/excalidraw": "^0.17.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "awesome-debounce-promise": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8",  <=========
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, but don't you need to use `react-app-rewired` for this to work?

Comment: @scibuff Ah yes correct, that what I have in the dependencies, I'll update the answer.